# How to make shell script launch python script?

Tags: python, shell

I need a `.command` file that can launch a python script in the same directory as it.

I have so far gotten this:

```
#!bin/bash
python /Users/username/Desktop/IF.py
```

But every time the Terminal returns the same error.

```
Last login: Sun Oct 11 01:48:38 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~ username$ /var/folders/m7/yf7p3vdj2mx0l9r7qb68rttc0000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/run 466235498.368.command.command ; exit;
/var/folders/m7/yf7p3vdj2mx0l9r7qb68rttc0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/run-466235498.368.command.command: line 3: bin/bash: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Please note the error is on line 3 of the 2 lines of code I have...

Comment: The shebang line needs to be `#!/bin/bash` *not* `#!bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just launch the python script itself from the get-go? You can add a shebang at the top like so:

```
#! /user/bin/env python
... the rest of your python script here
```

Then just give the script executable permissions:

```
chmod +x nameofscript.py
```

Then just launch it like so:

```
./nameofscript.py
```

In case you don't want the script to rely on the environment, just use the following shebang instead:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but if the script relies on the environment, it won't be loaded; which may have some side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the *shebang* (or *hashbang*). About [what is *shebang* (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

---

```
#!bin/bash
  ^ 
python /Users/username/Desktop/IF.py
```

This means the system will use `bin/bash` to run this program, but `bin/bash` means `path/bin/bash`.

For example, if you're in `/home` then the system will use `/home/bin/bash` to run this program.

---

I think you need this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /Users/username/Desktop/IF.py
```

Note that I replaced `#!bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash`.